# iPad keyboard won't Dismiss

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a very strange problem. I have a table view with text fields (`UITextField`) in way that the table view is used as a text editor (as `UITextView` doesn't satisfy my demands). Everything works well, except for one: the "hide keyboard" button — the button at the right-bottom corner of the virtual keyboard — doesn't work. It doesn't dismiss the keyboard. It doesn't send any method (delegate or target-action) either.

I added breakpoints everywhere. No methods are getting invoked when pushing the button. All other ones work. I do receive calls when editing begins or ends or when the return or clear button is pushed. It's not like my code crashed somewhere.

The thing is that this problem only occurs in my project. It doesn't occur elsewhere. And as I don't have a membership yet, I can only test in the Simulator.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: No. I decided to complete the app and then to test it on a real device.

Comment: The last I checked, it doesn't work on the real device either. I liked your solution (in an answer to another question) of drawing a hidden view over the hide button. Will give it a try and let you know later.

Answer (score 0):

Are you resigning first responder anywhere?
Try with:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that no method is called at all. No action method and no delegate method. But clearing and returning methods are fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this via google, figured some more info might help:

If the keyboard does not disappear when you click Done, you might not have connected the text field’s delegate or connected the view controller’s textField outlet to the text field. Be sure to check the text field’s connections: Control-click the text field to reveal the translucent connections panel. You should see filled-in circles next to the delegate outlet and the textField referencing outlet.

Comment: Thanks, but I discarded the design. My (now online) app now uses `UIWebView` along with a specially crafted document using `contenteditable`. It's much more efficient. By the way, I think the delegate was properly connected because I did receive other methods.